# Create a systemwide PHP function than can be used in any PHP project?

Tags: php

I often find myself writing something like this in projects to debug:

```
echo '</pre>';
var_dump($variable_to_debug);
echo '</pre>';
```

It works fine but can be kind of tedious to write out over and over again. What would be really cool would be to write a function to do this that could be called whenever I open a new PHP project. Is this even possible in PHP?

```
function debug($variable) {

   echo '</pre>';
   var_dump($variable);
   echo '</pre>';

}
```

Comment: You can look into the http://au2.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file configuration item

Comment: Similarly if you have nothing nice to say it would have been far easier to ignore this post and move on with your life.

Comment: Put it in an include file, and have all the scripts that want to use it do `require("functions.php");` to load it.

Comment: You can configure an include path in `php.ini`, so you can specify a central directory that always gets searched for include files.

Comment: Don't really see the point when this one-liner does the same thing ~ `echo '<pre>', print_r($variable, true), '</pre>';`

Comment: Also, you should look into using a debugger. It's much easier to step through your code as it executes instead of dumping text to an HTML document.